# select2 make container width fit text

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I'm looking for a way to increase the width of the container so that the text fits, instead of having it be truncated with `...`

[image]

I can't seem to get the container css attributes working e.g. `containerCss`. I get the error `Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/containerCss`.

I'm using select2 via `npm`

Comment: Have you tried by assigning width hard value? like `width:150px` or so

Comment: @M.HamzaMehmood don't really want to do that since there might be varied lengths of text. I'm trying to just attach a `padding-right: 10px` instead.

Comment: Right click on the html text input and look at its class name. use chrome inpector and experement setting the width css attribute on those generated elements. Find  the corresponding css class. Also look at the clase names of its container element. Then on the html page you use the jquery select library class names and set the width. Alternitevly read the docs on jquery select library on css styling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Right click and inspect the html text input and look at its class name. use chrome inpector and experement setting the width css attribute on those generated elements. Find the corresponding css class. Also look at the class names of its container element. Set the css of those elements to find a desired result. Then on the html page with the jquery selector library use the relevant class names and set the width. Alternitevly read the docs on jquery select library on css styling.

Comment: I'll check in a few days